# how to increase max_allowed_packet size without restart the server

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

Hi i am using codeigniter framework. I am running one query and request data from mysql. I have lot of data. It is running but gives the error as below.

**A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning**

```
Message: Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=182364

Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php

Line Number: 305
```

I have asked my service provider to increase `max_allowed_packet` size. Previously I've `245M`. they increased it `500M`. But there are problems with restarting the server. So, i want to increase it without restarting the server. Is it possible?. If it is possible please suggest how to set and where to set.

Comment: You can use `ini_set( string $varname , string $newvalue )` function to override the `php.ini` settings in your php file or you can define you changes in `.htaccess` file. [Click here to see](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8812260/3453169)

Comment: Is it work if i add in my function?

Comment: But why you want to add this in function.?.... simply define this in starting of you php file.

Comment: I added it in starting of my php file. But is is not working.

Comment: test my answer.

Comment: I am using codeigniter framework. I added my function in controller, so,please tell me where i can add the line which you are posted?

Comment: It is online server

Comment: it is saying #1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation

Comment: Any other solution please not with SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=1073741824; Because i don't have permissions to change.I tried with ini_set also. It did not work for me.

Answer (score 3):

`max_allowed_packet` This server variable can be set globally by running a query.

However, if you do not change it in the `my.ini/my.cnf` file, the value will reset when the server restarts, even if you set it globally.

To change the setting for everyone until the server restarts:

```
SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=1073741824;
```

Comment: I am using codeigniter framework. I added my function in controller, so,please tell me where i can add above line?

Comment: is your project in local server or online server?

Comment: It is online server, Yes i can access cpanel

Comment: Is it effect any another tables? It is online so, My clients are currently working now.

Comment: it does effect to all mysql not only one table.

Comment: it is saying #1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation

Comment: your user don't have permission you must have all privilege of super user?